# Continuity of a function and its limits

Tags: calculus, limits

Let $f(x)=min${$x^{3},sgn x$}.

Then:
\begin{align}
&f(0)=0;\\
&\lim_{x \rightarrow 0_{-}}f(x)=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0_{-}}sgnx=-1 \\
&\lim_{x \rightarrow 0_{+}}f(x)=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0_{+}}x^{3}=0 \\
\end{align}
According to my textbook this function is not continuous from neither right side nor left side. But why isn't this function continuous from right side? Since the definition say if:

> $\lim_{x\rightarrow a_{+}}f(x)=f(a)$

Then such function is continous from the right side. What is it that I am missing?

Comment: Does $\text{sgn}(x) = 1$ if $x > 0$ and $-1$ if $x < 0$? What about if $x = 0$?

Comment: @Olivier Sgn(0)=0

Comment: @Olivier $sgn0=0$, but as $f(x)$ on the interval $(0,1)$ is $x^3$ then the limit is 0

Comment: Yeah, I was just wondering about the definition of sgn. I'm usually doing (learning) math in french so I never encountered that name before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You miss nothing, your book is apparently wrong.

For visualization, see [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim%20x-%3E0%2b%20min%7Bx3,sgnx%7D.).

Comment: What does the red dot indicate? It's just where the x approaches?

Comment: @cryogenic Yes.